# How do I obtain the values of LinkedList<HashMap<String,String>>?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, linked-list, hashmap

I have this XMLParser:

```
public class XMLParser {
    private URL url;

    public XMLParser(String url){
        try {
            this.url = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> parse() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> entries = new LinkedList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> entry;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i=0; i<items.getLength(); i++) {
                entry = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                for (int j=0; j<properties.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node property = properties.item(j);
                    String name = property.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        entry.put(CheckNewPost.DATA_TITLE, property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        entry.put(CheckNewPost.DATA_LINK, property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
                entries.add(entry);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return entries;
    }

}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to obtain last value added on LinkedList and show it on a Toast. I tried this:

```
XMLParser par = new XMLParser(feedUrl);
        HashMap<String, String> entry = par.parse().getLast();
        String[] text = new String[] {entry.get(DATA_TITLE), entry.get(DATA_LINK)};
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
```

Evidently I don't have sufficient experience and I know almost nothing about Map, HashMap or so… The XMLParser is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

For iterating through all the values in your HashMap, you can use an EntrySet:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

And for only obtaining the last value, you can try this:

```
hashMap.get(hashMap.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the entry is HashMap that mean you need to get the Named/Value pairs out of the Map.  So for map, there is Named also known as Key or (hashed index), and for each "Key" there exist exactly one "value" so that.

```
Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<String, String>();
entries.put("Key1", "Value for Key 1");
entries.put("Key 2", "Key 2 value!");
entries.put("Key1", "Not the original value for sure!"); // replaced
```

and later you can get it as:

```
String val1 = entries.get("Key1"); // "Not the original value for sure!"
String val2 = entries.get("Key 2"); //"Key 2 value!"
```

and to loop through the Map you would do:

```
for (String key : entries.keySet()) {
   String value = entries.get(key);
}
```

Hope that help.  You can also google "Java Map example" for more.